# Bash loop not adding to array

Tags: bash

I am trying to add elements to an array in bash.  I am querying and looping over the query.

```
delete_arr=()
delete_arr+=("test")
mysql -e "$sql_statement" | while read directory_name; do 
if [ $counter -gt 0 ]
   then
     delete_arr+=($directory_name)
fi
let counter=counter+1
done

 for i in "${delete_arr[*]}"; do echo "$i"; done
```

The only output I am getting is `test`.  I should be getting a lot more data.  The query works and the data gets added to the array in the loop however when I jump out of the loop the array only contains `test`.I am doing nothing to reset the array.

Comment: See also [BashFAQ/024](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pipe, you are implicitly creating a new subshell with its own namespace. Try avoiding the pipe:

```
delete_arr=()
delete_arr+=("test")
while read directory_name
do 
    if [ "$counter" -gt 0 ]
    then
        delete_arr+=("$directory_name")
    fi
    counter=$((counter+1))
done < <(mysql -e "$sql_statement")

for i in "${delete_arr[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
```

Comment: I tried that but I am getting an error `done < <(mysql -e "$sql_statement")`

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: That is the error.  `line 103: `done < <(mysql -e "$sql_statement")'`

Comment: `syntax error near unexpected token `<'  done < <(mysql -e "$sql")'` Is the full error

Comment: fixed.  I had `#!/bin/sh` but i needed `#!/bin/bash`